# Как гарантировать новый ip адрес для каждого запроса к поде?

Tags: asp.net, микросервисы, kubernetes, веб-скрейпинг

Пишем мобильное приложение для ВУЗа.

Одной из фич должен быть просмотр расписания прямо внутри приложения.

API для получения расписания в открытом доступе нет, поэтому у меня есть отдельный микросервис, который занимается скраппингом университетского сайта. Всё бы ничего, всё прекрасно работает, даже относительно быстро.

НО для получения расписания одной группы приходится отправлять по 20 запросов к сайту в очень короткий промежуток времени. Такую наглость он ещё может вытерпеть, но если мой сервис начинает скраппить расписание сразу двух групп, я отлетаю с 503 кодом.

После несложных манипуляций удалось вычислить, что если отправлять больше 25 запросов в короткий промежуток времени, то тебе в куки записывается информация, что человек ты не очень надежный и пускать тебя сюда больше не стоит. Тут помогает или задание новых кук или банальное пересоздание HttpClient после бана.

А вот если отправить уже 50 запросов подряд, то тут сносят ip и собственно твои приключения заканчиваются.

Рассматриваю различные варианты решения этой проблемы и готов выслушать любые предложения.

А пока хочется услышать ваш совет, насчёт возможности реализовать одно из решений, которое пришло мне в голову.

Не зря я закусился про микросервисную архитектуру. Проект вообще является для меня учебным, поэтому дую по все дуды. Вот решил попробовать реализовать всю эту канетель "по модному" с поддержкой k8s, балансировкой нагрузки и возможностью масштабироваться. Все технологии для меня в новинку и сталкиваюсь с ними в первый раз.

Вообщем суть идеи: ограничить на уровне балансировщика, чтобы одна пода с сервисом для парсинга могла единовременно обрабатывать только один запрос на получение расписания. Далее для каждой поды установить VPN, чтобы внешний ip при обращении моего микросервиса  к сайту вуза менялся для каждого нового запроса на получение расписания.

Вопрос: как можно установить VPN в поду вместе с микросервисом, при этом чтобы на каждое обращение к инстансу микросервиса внешний ip для сайта, который я скрапплю, менялся?

Comment: может стоит попробовать решить эту проблему? "НО для получения расписания одной группы приходится отправлять по 20 запросов к сайту в очень короткий промежуток времени."

Comment: вы пишете какую-то там программу для какого-то там вуза, и вам требуется информация от этого вуза. похоже, ошибка ваша состоит в том, что вы не попытались получить эту информацию от вуза. к программированию/администрированию ваш вопрос точно не имеет отношения.

Answer (score 0):

твой подход никуда не годится с точки зрения результата, но с т.з. процесса ты разучил кубера, поды и т.п. - это гут. Если пингать универ одновременно с 8 адресов, он забанит все 8 и у него появятся вопросы на которые специально обученные люди будут искать ответы - тебе это надо в текущей нестабильной обстановке? если пишешь приложение ДЛЯ вуза- зайди к ректору и попроси доступ к апи, с адекватным лимитом. А перед этим зайди к вуз-админу и оставь там бутылочку коньяку (базовые алгоритмы)